# Regex for timestamp

Tags: python, regex

I'm terrible at regex apparently, it makes no sense to me...

I'd like an expression for matching a time, like `01:23:45` within a string.

I tried this

```
(r'(([0-9]*2)[:])*2([0-9]*2)
```

but it's not working. I need to be able to get the entire timestamp. Others I've tried have only found like 2 digits in it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have your repeaters wrong I'm afraid:

```
r'\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}'
```

The correct syntax is `{n,m}` for minimum and maximum digits, or `{n}` for an exact match. The `\d` character class is also easier to use that `[0-9]`; it means the same thing for regular (non-Unicode) matching.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Yup, clarified.

Comment: While your answer is correct, I think this `\d\d:\d\d:\d\d` one is more intuitively understandable and obvious.

Comment: @Engineer: That depends on your experience level, and the OP's underlying problem was how to match repeating patterns.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, I agree,that it depends on experience level, but when the time for reviewing your code comes, you need to understand/remember your code as faster as you can. IMHO I don't believe `\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}` is more obvious than `\d\d:\d\d:\d\d`.

Comment: @Engineer: I disagree, and it's a micro-optimization. You'll still have to grok `{n}` syntax, as for larger `n` values and more complex repeated groups you are not going to write the pattern out `n` times. And then I haven't even touched upon the `{n,m}` construct..

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am aware of `{n,m}` construct.And I didn't mean 'complex repeated groups' . I just mean current case, when you need to *validate time* (`00:00:00`).

Answer (score 5):

Why even use a regex - use the proper datetime functions and get validation thrown in for free...

```
from datetime import datetime
time = datetime.strptime('01:23:45', '%H:%M:%S').time()
print time.hour, time.minute, time.second
# 1 23 45
```

Duff time:

```
>>> datetime.strptime('99:45:63', '%H:%M:%S')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#36>", line 1, in <module>
    datetime.strptime('99:45:63', '%H:%M:%S')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '99:45:63' does not match format '%H:%M:%S'
```

Comment: It could be the OP has a larger string that *contains* a timestamp. Extract first before passing it to `strptime` sort of situation.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing. This is still cool though, thanks!

Comment: @user1159454 Fair play: A good combo would be to extract using the regex's you've been provided, then possibly validate - I take it the *entire* timestamp is not conveniently selectable from the string?

Comment: No, the regex is enough for this mission, but thanks! I'll keep this in mind for bigger tasks

Answer (score 2):

The proper specifier for repeating the previous match twice is `{2}`.

```
[0-9]{2}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `*2` you should be using `{2}`.

```
[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

timestamp_regex = r'(2[0-3]|[01][0-9]|[0-9]):([0-5][0-9]|[0-9]):([0-5][0-9]|[0-9])'


print(bool(re.match(timestamp_regex, '01:23:45')))  # True
print(bool(re.match(timestamp_regex, '01:01:45')))  # True
print(bool(re.match(timestamp_regex, '01:01:01')))  # True
print(bool(re.match(timestamp_regex, '1:1:1')))     # True
print(bool(re.match(timestamp_regex, '25:1:1')))    # False
```

demo: https://ideone.com/eE0Pnb