# How to ensure that the timezone is entered in the ISO UTC format within the request body?

Tags: python, fastapi

I am using `pydantic` within `FastAPI` and I need to ensure that the timestamp is always entered in the `UTC ISO` format such as `2015-09-01T16:09:00:000Z`.

```
from typing import Optional
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from datetime import datetime


app = FastAPI()

measurements = [
    {
      "timestamp": "2015-09-01T16:09:00:000Z",
      "temperature": 27.1
    },
    {
        "timestamp": "2016-09-01T16:09:00:000Z",
        "temperature": 21.3
    }
]

class MeasurementIn(BaseModel):
    timestamp: datetime
    temperature: Optional[float]    

@app.post("/measurements")
async def create_measurement(m: MeasurementIn, response: Response):
    measurements.append(m)
```

The above code is working but it is also accepting datetime in other formats. I want to strictly restrict it to UTC ISO Format. I have tried to change the `timestamp` to `timestamp: datetime.utcnow().isoformat()` but it is not working.

Comment: Use the [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665582/regex-for-timestamp) to check the input you receive.

Comment: @ChrisSc should I update my `app.post` and use the regular expression there? can you please provide how the updated code would look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import `re`

```py
import re
```

Declare the regular expression

```py
timestamp_regex = r'[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T([0-9]{2}:){3}[0-9]{3}Z'
```

Check the parameter (note that this assumes `m` is a valid dictionary)

```py
@app.post("/measurements")
async def create_measurement(m: MeasurementIn, response: Response):
  if bool(re.match(timestamp_regex, m["timestamp"])):
    measurements.append(m)
  else:
    # we have an error that needs to be handled
```

Comment: I think we need to convert timestamp to string `str(m["timestamp"])`

Comment: Yes, if it isn't one already. Assuming it isn't already a string and to keep consistent with the sample data in the original question, it should be converted to a string and assigned back to `m["timestamp"]` when **create_measurement** is entered